# How can I drag a widget not directly but through slider widget in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, drag, flutter-animation

I want to add a dragging effect on a particular widget using slider.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you provide more details life gif of your desire out and code-snippet that you've tried so far?

Comment: see attached images please see if you can help me thanks

Comment: @YeasinSheikh                check it brother